# (Temporarily) disabling backtracking in Eisbach method

Tags: isabelle

I have a method that generates a large number of possible states, and when chaining it using `,` with a (conditional) `fail` or `tactic no_tac`, the resulting combined method takes a very long time to terminate and causes the Isabelle interface to lag. However, when the same methods are applied separately using two `apply`s, termination is very quick. Is there a way to force the Eisbach method to not backtrack on failure, and instead just fail right away? (In essence, functioning as `apply <method> apply cond_fail` rather than `apply (<method>, cond_fail)`?)

Comment: Do you mean something like [`once` in LTac](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/ltac.html#hevea_tactic224)?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Essentially. I eventually ended up finding a solution a colleague left in a library file, actually, which I'll post tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this directly in vanilla Eisbach, but it is relatively easy to define new combinators (i.e. higher-order methods).

We have a few of these in https://github.com/seL4/l4v/blob/796887/lib/Eisbach_Methods.thy. For your case specifically, the `determ` method looks like what you want. It lifts the ML `DETERM` combinator into Eisbach:

```
method_setup determ =
 \<open>Method.text_closure >> (fn m => fn ctxt => fn facts =>
   let
     fun tac st' = method_evaluate m ctxt facts st'
   in SIMPLE_METHOD (DETERM tac) facts end)
\<close>
```

(https://github.com/seL4/l4v/blob/796887/lib/Eisbach_Methods.thy#L59)

Those combinators have since been added to the Isabelle distribution and should appear in the upcoming Isabelle2018 release.

`DETERM` cuts off all backtracking, and passes on only the first alternative. With that

`apply (determ <f>, g)`

should be equivalent to

```
apply f
apply g
```

Comment: This is equivalent to the method I obtained from Peter Lammich, though his is structured slightly differently (`Method.text_closure >> (fn (text) => fn ctxt => fn using => fn st => Seq.DETERM (Method.evaluate_runtime text ctxt using) st)` instead)

Comment: @lsf37 that is a nice collection of method combinators. Could you add this to the distribution?

Comment: @larsh Now done. At least the ones that were compatible with Pure.